# CSS auto width middle element with floats

Tags: css

I have a responsive top bar menu. On the left I have 2 buttons in a `<ul>` element with `float:left`. On the right I have another `<ul>` element with a `float:right` align.
In the middle of the two lists, I have one `<p>` element that receives dynamic text.

This works on large screens, but in the small devices the last `<ul>` goes to down.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49zjn/1/
Resize the Result panel to view my problem.

Any ideas of how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: You havent really stated what you want done with it... What do you want? The `<p>` to start a new line and not push the `float: right;` `<ul>` down?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
#right { float:right; }
```

Try

```
#right { position:absolute; top:0; right:0 }
```

Comment: And now items can superimpose and be unreadable? This *creates* a new problem... Don't use absolute positioning for layout (at all or at least without extra care)

Comment: You are in the right way! Is something like this... But to avoid more problems, I decided to remove this `<p>` on small devices.

Answer (score 0):

What is the behavior that you would like? Do you want the status to resize or be the first to drop down to the next line?

The following will make the status drop down first...it's all about the order of your elements.

```
#left { float:left; }
#left li { display:inline-block; }
#right { float:right; }
#status { overflow: hidden; float:left; }
li, p { padding:5px; border: 1px solid #000; }

<div id="bar">
    <ul id="left">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="right">
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="status">Some long dynamic text here with system status</p>
</div>
```

Give more specifics on what you'd like (if this isn't it) and I'll take another crack at it.

Good luck!